# How to theme exposed filter items in views - drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, view, drupal-views

I'm attempting to put a bit of style on a specific set of exposed filters on a view that I have created.

The view is called user_search and so I have created views-exposed-form--user-search.tpl.php and that didn't work (all it did was remove the exposed filters but still displayed the view). views-exposed-form--user-search--page.tpl.php also got the same results.

Even if it did work, I still don't know what to put there to get the form to show up, just so that I can add styles or container divs.

`print drupal_render($form);` did not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution after a lot of digging.

First, you have to find the views-exposed-form.tpl.php file which should be located in `sites/all/modules/views/theme/` folder. We're using the acquia stack so it was located in the `vendor/` folder.

Copy this to `themes/YOUR-THEME/` folder and rename it to `views-exposed-form--your-view-name.tpl.php`

If you only want to effect a specific display of your view name it to `views-exposed-form--your-view-name--display.tpl.php`

You can then use the existing framework to edit it as you see fit. Here's an example.

```
<?php
// $Id: views-exposed-form.tpl.php,v 1.4.4.1 2009/11/18 20:37:58 merlinofchaos Exp $
/**
 * @file views-exposed-form.tpl.php
 *
 * This template handles the layout of the views exposed filter form.
 *
 * Variables available:
 * - $widgets: An array of exposed form widgets. Each widget contains:
 * - $widget->label: The visible label to print. May be optional.
 * - $widget->operator: The operator for the widget. May be optional.
 * - $widget->widget: The widget itself.
 * - $button: The submit button for the form.
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
?>
<?php if (!empty($q)): ?>
  <?php
    // This ensures that, if clean URLs are off, the 'q' is added first so that
    // it shows up first in the URL.
    print $q;
  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="views-exposed-form">
  <div class="views-exposed-widgets clear-block">
    <?php foreach($widgets as $id => $widget): ?>
      <div class="views-exposed-widget">
        <?php if (!empty($widget->label)): ?>
          <label for="<?php print $widget->id; ?>">
            <?php print $widget->label; ?>
          </label>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (!empty($widget->operator)): ?>
          <div class="views-operator">
            <?php print $widget->operator; ?>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="views-widget">
          <?php print $widget->widget; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <div class="views-exposed-widget">
      <?php print $button ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt about how to theme a part of a page, install the [Theme Developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer). It will allow you to see what theme file or function is currently outputting a specific area of the page, as well as what files or functions can be used to override it. See the [screencast](http://drupal.org/node/209561) for more detailed information.